# How do I submit form input data with POST request when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post, xmlhttprequest

So far, I have a basic form that gets 2 inputs. The submit button successfully adds the new record to the SQLite database but with the values from the input elements. I am definitely missing how to properly set this up in my JavaScript code but I just don't know how to implement it.

JavaScript

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

const items_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/items"

function addingItems(){
    xhttp.open("POST", items_url, true);
    // Value implementation here maybe...
    console.log("Form button has been clicked for item entry submission");
    console.log(xhttp);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

HTML

```
<form method="POST" class="addItem">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="item_title" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number" name="item_number" required>
    <button id="submitItem" type="submit" form="addItem" value="Submit" onclick="addingItems()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `FormData` to ajax object in JavaScript:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

const items_url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/items"

function addingItems(){
    xhttp.open("POST", items_url, true);
    console.log("Form button has been clicked for item entry submission");
    console.log(xhttp);
    var form=new FormData()
    form.append("item_title",document.getElementsByName("item_title")[0].value)
    form.append("item_number",document.getElementsByName("item_number")[0].value)
    xhttp.send(form);
}
```

```
<form method="POST" class="addItem">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="item_title" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number" name="item_number" required>
    <button id="submitItem" value="Submit" onclick="addingItems()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented the above but have now encountered this error upon clicking "Submit": `Error response
Error code: 501

Message: Unsupported method ('POST').

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation.`

Answer (score 1):

Using  type="submit" will cause the page to reload, you can change that behavior either by using type="button" or by using event.preventDefault(); in your addingItems() function.
And then on the click of button you can call a function which will get your form data and send to your server
Following are the links that you can follow to achieve your target.
Using [AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)
Using [XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<form method="POST" class="addItem" id="my-form-id">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="item_title" required>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Number" name="item_number" required>
    <button id="submitItem" type="submit" form="addItem" value="Submit" onclick="addingItems()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the js function to be:

```
function addingItems(){
    xhttp.open("POST", items_url, true);
    var formData = new FormData( document.getElementById("my-form-id") );
    xhttp.send(formData);
}
```

Now the `FormData` class is supported by most browsers, but if you are targeting some legacy browsers, you can try this:

```
function addingItems(){
    xhttp.open("POST", items_url, true);
    var input = document.getElementById("my-input-id");
    var inputData = encodeURIComponent(input.value);
    var postData = input.name + "=" + inputData;
    xhttp.send(postData);
}
```

*I don't know if the later will work as is, might have to debug a little.*